# trouble adding new <li> to <ul> onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to add a list element to an existing ul using a function from an onclick like this:

```
<span style="color:red;">Bob</span>
```

If i hard code it in the HTML it works fine:

```
<ul id="LsUL">
<li><span style="color:blue;">Joe</span></li>
<li><span style="color:green;">Frank</span></li>
</ul>
```

But using a function it dose not work

```js
function changeText2() {
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<span style="color:red;">Bob</span>'));
  document.getElementById("LsUL").appendChild(entry);
}
changeText2();
```

```html
<ul id="LsUL">
  <li><span style="color:blue;">Joe</span></li>
  <li><span style="color:green;">Frank</span></li>
</ul>
```

The output should be like this:

- Joe (blue)
- Frank (green)
- bob (red)

But I get this:

```
Joe (blue)
Frank (green)
<span style="color:red;">bob</span>
```

I cant seem to get it to work any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: createTextNode inserts text, not HTML. Try [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead

Answer (score 4):

`createTextNode` will do exactly what it sounds like - create a **text** node. Whatever you pass in, it will always create a text node, composed only of text - it won't create child elements.

Element nodes can contain text nodes, but not the other way around - text nodes can't contain anything but text.

If you want to set the new `li`'s HTML, use `innerHTML`:

```
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Bob</span>';
list.appendChild(entry);
```

You can also do it all at once with `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li><span style="color:red;">Bob</span></li>');
```

Comment: Thank you very much i looked all over for an answer!